# the function setWebpackOptimizationSplitChunks in customize-cra does not work properly?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-app-rewired, customize-cra

The application I created using create-react-app uses customize-cra and react-app-rewired to override some configurations of webpack. When I use the setWebpackOptimizationSplitChunks function and run pnpm start, the project cannot run correctly and stays at Starting. the development server... , what is the problem? Or are there other solutions that cover webpack? Because I don't want to run eject.

#### code

```
const {
  override,
  disableEsLint,
  overrideDevServer,
  watchAll,
  setWebpackOptimizationSplitChunks,
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(
    // usual webpack plugin
    disableEsLint(),
    setWebpackOptimizationSplitChunks({
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false,
    }),
  ),
  devServer: overrideDevServer(
    // dev server plugin
    watchAll()
  )
};
```

After adding `setWebpackOptimizationSplitChunks` function, run `pnpm start` the command line will be stuck at

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXzSf.png)

`setWebpackOptimizationSplitChunks` can run normally if this function is removed.

react version is 18.2.0